# Changing site URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm finding a lot about creating pretty URIs and whatnot using mod_rewrite but what I'm looking for is a way to remove elements of a URL (as far as the viewer is concerned) and not just moving stuff around and/or reorganizing.

I need this:

http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar

to be this:

http://www.mysite.com/bar

Basically, let's get rid of /foo in the URL.

Is that possible?

Comment: What's the logic behind this? Is this just for one controller?

Comment: Just to clean up the URL, really. It's a Wordpress installation and it's sitting in a dir one down from public_html. Just trying to clean things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by simply dropping what you want to lose:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$  $1  [R=301,NE,L]
```

That should effectively remove `foo/` from your URL. If you don't want the address bar to reflect this change, remove `R=301`. The `NE` parameter is there to make sure that the request is not escaped.

Comment: Doesn't this do the exact opposite of what he wants? He wants the URL to be example.com/bar, and refer to the file at /foo/bar. This rewrite rule seems to turn example.com/foo/bar into the file at /bar. Or maybe I just don't know enough about mod_rewrite?

Comment: If he wants to refer to /bar as /foo/bar, then he would need a rule for each /foo he wanted to reference

Comment: Hmm... so something like:

RewriteRule (these|are|the|dirs|I|want|to|filter|out)/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,NE,L]

Comment: @Andrew: This is what I've got now, modified w/ your suggestion. Still doesn't want to work. You might see why where I don't:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog2/index.php
RewriteRule ^blog2/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Remove your `RewriteBase` statement.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Most of these instructions came from [here, "Giving Wordpress its Own Directory"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

If it is Wordpress specifically, this can be handled by adding an index.php that looks like this to the directory you want to be the base:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./blog2/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

In Wordpress settings, you need to let it know the difference between the "actual" Wordpress URL and the one you want everyone else to use:

- WordPress address (URL): http://mysite.com/blog2
- Blog address (URL): http://mysite.com/

(These were under "Settings" for me...)

Also, I cannot remember if this is done automatically or not (I thought it was), but the .htaccess where you put the index.php file will need to look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I guess this was more a questions about WP rather than mod_rewrite.